# First BindingNavigator Record data not loading

Tags: c#, winforms

On my initial load, my first record is not loading data from table2 to my form (DataBinded TextBoxes). If I navigate to the second and back to the first it loads. Any ideas?

```
 public partial class myForm : Form
 {
    public int bindingPosition {get; set;}
    private void myForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       this.tableAdapter1.Fill(this.myDataSet.Table1);
       this.tableAdapter2.Fill(this.myDataSet.Table2);
    }
    if (bindingPosition >=0)
    {
       //Navigates to specific record if bindingPosition variable is set
       //set by passing Convert.ToInt32(BindingNavigator.PositionItem.Text) from another form
       myBindingSource.Position = (bindingPosition -1);
    }
    myBindingNavigator_RefreshItems(sender,e);
 }
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on `this.tableAdapter1.Fill(...)` and the step above it, how many rows does Table 2 contain ?

Comment: @mrlucmorin After I fill tableApadpter1, table 2 has 0 rows. After I fill tableAdapter2, table 2 has 827 rows (Correct amount)

Comment: Ok, so you know that the data is getting pulled from the DB, but your code seems a bit strange. You seem to have edited out important sections of code, so it's hard to understand what you're doing.

Comment: @mrlucmorin For example TextBox1, TextBox2, and TextBox3 are databinded to 3 columns in table 1. TextBox4, TextBox5, and TextBox6 are databinded to columns in table 2. TextBox1, TextBox2, and TextBox3 all are populated on initial load for myForm. However, textBox4, textBox5, and textBox 6 are all blank. I have confirmed that values are populated for the specific record in table 2. I don't know what else to do except programatically change the bindingNavigator from record 1 to record 2 and then back to record 1 on load.